# MY SQL Sub query returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql-server

MY SQL--->

```
insert into table b (col list)
select id,
       Col2 = ( select col from table B where col5 = 'true'),
       Col3 = ( select col from table B where col4 = 'true')
from table a
```

in this i am getting error

> Err] 1242 - Sub query returns more than 1 row

is there any another method to do the same functionality?

Comment: Error message tells everything, you try to Col2 and/or Col3 pass multiple values from subquery

Comment: can you tell me your table structure with some data

Comment: You've tagged this as both MySql and Sql-Server, it can't be both...

Comment: You can always add `LIMIT 1` (mysql) or `TOP 1` (mssql) but I would first ask myself if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You inner queries are returning more than 1 values. This will work since I have limited the inner query result to 1 but I am not sure whether your requirements are satisfied or not.

```
 insert into table b (col list)
  select id,
   Col2 = ( select col from (select col from table B where col5 = 'true' limit 0,1) as alias  ),
   Col3 = ( select col from (select col from table B where col4 = 'true'  limit 0,1) as alias 2)
 from table a
```

Comment: i dont want to insert 0 or 1 , i have to insert another column value if its true then col1 or " ", it have to be one to one mapping.

Comment: use if else then as  Col2 = ( select if(col1="abc", col1, " ");

this will return col1 if col1 has value abc